# Error:no such table ios sqlite3

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
DBStockManager.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <sqlite3.h>

@interface DBStockManager : NSObject

@property sqlite3 *databaseHandle;
@property NSString *databasePath;
@property NSString *databaseName;

-(void)initDatabase;
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase;
-(void) insertintoDataBase;

@end

DBStockManger.m

#import "DBStockManager.h"

@implementation DBStockManager

static DBStockManager *_database;

@synthesize databasePath;
@synthesize databaseName;



-(void)initDatabase{

    databaseName=@"stock.db";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
}

-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase{

    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success)
        return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:databaseName];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
}

-(void) insertintoDataBase{

    sqlite3 *database;
    BOOL returnCode='YES';
    NSLog(@"Called insertdatabase");
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK){
        NSLog(@"database opened");
        char *sqlstatment="insert into user_stock(user_name,user_password) values(?,?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatment;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlstatment, -1, &compiledStatment, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatment, 1, "nimi", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
             sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatment, 2, "anand", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        }
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatment)!=SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Error:%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

}



- (void)dealloc {
    sqlite3_close(_databaseHandle);

}

@end


ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _dbManager = [[DBStockManager alloc]init];
    [_dbManager initDatabase];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)loginClicked:(id)sender {
    _dbManager.insertintoDataBase;

}
@end
```

I am new to ios app using sqlite3. I have created stock.db file using terminal. Created a table and added few records in the table.I am trying to insert a record into the database upon click of the button which is not happening.

This is the code for inserting a record into the table user_Stock.
I always get an error of Error:no such table: user_stock. But I have the table in the database. Please advise how to proceed.

database:

```
Last login: Thu Dec  1 13:00:25 on ttys003
thiyagarajans-MacBook-Pro:~ rajkumar$ ls
Applications    Downloads   Movies      Public      stock.sql
Desktop     IdeaProjects    Music       eclipse     student.db
Documents   Library     Pictures    stock.db
thiyagarajans-MacBook-Pro:~ rajkumar$ .databases
-bash: .databases: command not found
thiyagarajans-MacBook-Pro:~ rajkumar$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.14.0 2016-07-26 15:17:14
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main                                                                       
sqlite> .open stock.db
sqlite> select * from user_Stock;
1|nirmal|anand
2|nimi.hbk|kingkong@123
sqlite>
```

Comment: 1) Check whether the table name in the db is correct or not. 2) Also if you are running on simulator, open the application's document directory in finder and check the db whether it have the mentioned table in it or not. 3) Delete the app and run it again

Comment: hi Midhun, I am running on simulator .how to open documents directory in simulator and also how to delete the app ?

Comment: 1) Just print the `databasePath` to console and in finder choose go to folder option and past the path you got in your console. 2) Long click on the app icon in your simulator till a close button arrives. Click on the close button

Comment: I get below as db path: /Users/rajkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A4701999-4D7C-44ED-BB06-8419B498DCC6/data/Containers/Data/Application/3255FA7E-475A-4853-8542-A6705D70D855/Documents/stock.db  and here is my terminal output: thiyagarajans-MacBook-Pro:~ rajkumar$ cd /Users/rajkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A4701999-4D7C-44ED-BB06-8419B498DCC6/data/Containers/Data/Application/C6BC01BD-C8AF-435A-B46B-2E0143591750/Documents/
thiyagarajans-MacBook-Pro:Documents rajkumar$ ls
stock.db

Comment: I did reset the app that deleted the installed apps. but still i get the same error.

Comment: Posted the details of database

Comment: I would create a new db file, then in it make a new tbl called z with one column zz, then try it. This starts everything clean & minimal, just to eliminate any weird issues. With the simulator open, clk Simulator>Reset Content and Settings, to delete the cache of simulator dirs. The tricky part with the simulators is that you end up with multiple copies of the sqlite file everywhere--you have one in your xcode proj dir, then one in each simulator's Bundle dir, then one in each simulator's Documents dir. Only make changes to the proj dir one, and always Reset to ensure you get the new file.

Comment: @Harish Change `user_stock` to `user_Stock` in your insert query